# Using HTML checkbox and JavaScript to switch between standard and military time

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a little clock app that displays standard time on load and has a toggle button that can change the display to military time. However, I would like to use the toggle switch to be able to go back and forth between standard and military time. Right now I can only click the toggle button one time and it switches to military time but can't be clicked more than once.

I'll include a codepin and github link. Any resources or advice will be very helpful.

Thanks!

https://codepen.io/constequalsexcel/pen/dyoyXrM

https://github.com/Web-Dev-Jr/Clock-App/tree/master/Clock-App

'''

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Digital Clock</title>
    <meta name="Sam Kautz" content="Digital Clock">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="clock">
        <div>
            <h1 id="time"></h1>
            <h3>Toggle Time</h3>
            <label class="switch" id="millitary-toggler">
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="mdy">
            <h1 id="weekday"></h1>
            <h1 id="month"></h1>
            <h1 id="date"></h1>
            <h1 id="year"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

'''

```
/*********************
    Time/Date Styling
*********************/

.mdy h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.mdy {

}

.clock {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
}

/*********************
    Toggler Styling
*********************/

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

    /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
    .switch input {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

    .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
    }

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

    .slider.round:before {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

'''

'''

```
let time = setInterval(timer, 0);

function timer() {
    let hms = new Date();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = hms.toLocaleTimeString();
}

let setWeekday = new Date();
let weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

let n = weekday[setWeekday.getDay()];
document.getElementById("weekday").innerHTML = n + " - "

let d = new Date();
let months =
    ["January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"];
document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = months[d.getMonth()];

let getTodaysDate = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = getTodaysDate.getDate() + ",";

    let getFullYear = new Date();
    document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = getFullYear.getFullYear();


document.getElementById("millitary-toggler").addEventListener("click", millitaryTime);

function millitaryTime() {
    clearTimeout(time);

    var millitaryHours = new Date();
    var newMillitaryHours = millitaryHours.getHours();

    var millitaryMinutes = new Date();
    var newMillitaryMinutes = millitaryMinutes.getMinutes();

    var millitarySeconds = new Date();
    var newMillitarySeconds = millitarySeconds.getSeconds();

    let millitaryTimer = setInterval(millitaryTime, 0);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newMillitaryHours + ":" + newMillitaryMinutes + ":" + newMillitarySeconds;
}


function millitaryTime() {

    if (getElementById(millitary-toggler))
    clearTimeout(time);

    var millitaryHours = new Date();
    var newMillitaryHours = millitaryHours.getHours();

    var millitaryMinutes = new Date();
    var newMillitaryMinutes = millitaryMinutes.getMinutes();

    var millitarySeconds = new Date();
    var newMillitarySeconds = millitarySeconds.getSeconds();

    let millitaryTimer = setInterval(millitaryTime, 0);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newMillitaryHours + ":" + newMillitaryMinutes + ":" + newMillitarySeconds;
}
```

'''

Comment: It happens because you run into an infinite loop. You invoke function `millitaryTime()` in the interval which is created inside of this exact function. Means every time function is called a new interval is created and invokes itself again. You can only click the button once because all memory is used to handle that. Also if you only update clock every 1sec I think you can easily pass 500 as a time param to the intervals. It still gets approximately 2 chances to update the time but will increase performance by a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

An example solution for you. It's not ideal but works. As you see you can use one interval and inside of the function that is invoked get data about a specific time. This way you avoid memory leaks.

---

### Note

I have added styles to `.clock` at the beginning of CSS so it displays correctly in the snippet.

---

```js
let clock = setInterval(displayTime, 500);

function getBaseTime() { 
    let hms = new Date();
    return hms.toLocaleTimeString();
}

let setWeekday = new Date();
let weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

let n = weekday[setWeekday.getDay()];
document.getElementById("weekday").innerHTML = n + " - "

let d = new Date();
let months =
    ["January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"];
document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = months[d.getMonth()];

let getTodaysDate = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = getTodaysDate.getDate() + ",";

    let getFullYear = new Date();
    document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = getFullYear.getFullYear();

function getMilitaryTime() {
    var militaryHours = new Date();
    var newMilitaryHours = militaryHours.getHours();

    var militaryMinutes = new Date();
    var newMilitaryMinutes = militaryMinutes.getMinutes();

    var militarySeconds = new Date();
    var newMilitarySeconds = militarySeconds.getSeconds();

    return newMilitaryHours + ":" + newMilitaryMinutes + ":" + newMilitarySeconds;
}

function displayTime(){
  if(document.querySelector("#military-toggler input:checked")){
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = getMilitaryTime()
  }
  else{
    
     document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = getBaseTime()
  }
}
```

```css
/*********************
 ADDED ONLY FOR SNIPPET
*********************/

.clock{
  height: unset !important
}



/*********************
    Time/Date Styling
*********************/

.mdy h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.mdy {

}

.clock {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
}

/*********************
    Toggler Styling
*********************/

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

    /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
    .switch input {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

    .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
    }

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

    .slider.round:before {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Digital Clock</title>
    <meta name="Sam Kautz" content="Digital Clock">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="clock">
        <div>
            <h1 id="time"></h1>
            <h3>Toggle Time</h3>
            <label class="switch" id="military-toggler">
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="mdy">
            <h1 id="weekday"></h1>
            <h1 id="month"></h1>
            <h1 id="date"></h1>
            <h1 id="year"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is odd but this line; document.querySelector("#military-toggler input:checked", is what really cleared things up. That is what I was missing. Thanks again for taking the time!